# Breakdown of AWS S3 DataTransfer-Out-Bytes costs per object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an app where various customers upload files to a single S3 bucket in my AWS account. Over time the costs of `DataTransfer-Out-Bytes` have grown and I want to see if there's some way to understand which objects/URLs are getting the most traffic or contributing the most to costs.

I found a way to get per-bucket cost breakdown but is there any way to get an idea of which objects/URLs are contributing the most toward the costs (or receiving the most traffic)?

Comment: Turn on the logging, then analyze them. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerLogs.html

Comment: Thanks. Any more info on how I could "analyze" S3 logs to understand what objects are costing me the most?